# Old answer which I no longer consider correct, what is the best approach?

Tags: discussion, answers

A year ago I asked a question about CSS:

[CSS display div on another div:hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359300/css-display-div-on-another-divhover)

I have just edited because it was hard to read, and the code wouldn't run because of its bad formatting.

You can see the old version and the revision here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32359300/revisions

Upon re-reading of the answers, I realized the answer with the most upvotes (3), which I originally accepted, is actually really bad advice. The author of the answer, however, answered the question correctly in the comments, after I asked further doubts.

I have left the following comment:

> I have edited this old question to make it more readable. After some time, I no longer consider your answer appropriate, but this last comment you made answers it better [...] I am considering deleting the question, but if you modify your answer with your comment I will keep it.

Take into account that the answer he gave (without the comment) was really  not good advice (using `!important` instead of fixing the selector priority issue I had) and it wasn't (in my eyes) good input for SO.

Do you think my approach to this issue is appropriate? What could I have done better?

Comment: It is fine. Wait few days to see if the user adds this into his answer; otherwise, edit it yourself.

Comment: To complement fedorqui, if there's a proper answer in the comments, edit the answer with the proper solution and accept it.

Comment: Yep, I ended up doing exactly that. The guy who answered the question hasn't logged in in almost a month, so I figured it wouldn't hurt if I edited it myself. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Small note: you said «I am considering deleting the question» but you wouldn't be able to do that if there are upvoted answers.

Comment: I see! Somebody just told me. I think editing the answer myself was the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Folding comments written by the original author of a post into the post is a place where it is hard to go wrong.  Beyond making the original post unreadable, that is.

If the comment is fresh, and the user is actively engaged in conversation at this moment, I will comment and ask them to do it.  Otherwise, I will simply edit it directly into the content, include in the edit description that I'm folding the original author's comments into the answer (or question), then ping the original author with a comment saying what I did and ask them if I worded it right.

I do not recall having a negative response from this approach from other users or the original author.  The biggest risk is that if you are under the 2k threshold you might be rejected: a really good description in the edit can help there.

Comment: If under 2k rep, it is *important* to make sure your "really good description" explicitly states that you are moving the OP's comments into the post. That will, hopefully, get reviewers to verify that you are, in fact, moving comments made by the OP and approve the edit. Without such a description of your edit, it is likely that reviewers will reject the edit as conflicting with the author's intent.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, I think I covered that in paragraph 2?

Comment: You did for your own description for your own edit.  But, in the following paragraph, you just said that a <2k rep user might have the edit rejected without "a really good description". You have nothing that equates "a really good description" with what you are doing for your own edit, nor describes what you mean by "a really good description".  Something like: "a really god description in the edit, that explicitly states you are folding the original author's comments into the question, can help there" would make it more clear. I just feel it should be crystal clear for the <2k users.